# Segfault 11 when Malloc

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, malloc

I'm running valgrind to debug a code where when I malloc it segfaults at this line:

```
CalComp **const pcomp; //Have to define it like this
(*pcomp) = malloc(sizeof(CalComp));
```

I'm not really sure why this is happening.

This is CalComp:

```
typedef struct CalComp {    // calendar's (sub)component
    char *name;         // uppercase
    int nprops;         // no. of properties
    CalProp *prop;      // -> first property (or NULL)
    int ncomps;         // no. of subcomponents
    CalComp *comp[];    // component pointers (flexible array member)
} CalComp;
```

Aren't I mallocing it correctly? Or am I missing something? I'm getting Segfault: 11.

Answer (score 5):

`pcomp` is uninitialised. Dereferencing an uninitialised pointer invoke undefined behavior.
First, you need to allocate memory for `pcomp`. Assuming you are allocating an array of 1 `CalCamp *`, then

```
pcomp = malloc(sizeof(CalComp *));
```

and then allocate memory for `*pcomp` (or `pcomp[0]`).

Comment: No, you are not. `pcomp` is a pointer to pointer to `CalComp` and you are allocating memory to `*pcomp`.

Comment: when you say (*pcomp), what is pcomp here?? who initialized it? that is what haccks is doing above..without telling compiler what address pcomp hold you are deferencing it using *pcomp and initializing with another address. What do you expect..??